# fijar la fecha del dia anterior a las 00:00 horas

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito sacar en MySQL la fecha del día anterior a las 00:00 horas.

Por ejemplo si hoy es `21/11/2017 11:57:00`, la fecha resultante debería ser
`20/11/2017 0:00:00.000`.

En sybase lo saco de esta forma

```
SELECT dateadd (dd, 0,convert (varchar (10),getdate(), 101))
```

Sin embargo en MySQL no lo consigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que calcular la fecha y hora actual menos un día y menos la hora actual.

Algo como

```
SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL CURRENT_TIME HOUR_SECOND
```

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `CURRENT_DATE` (o `CURDATE())`, que te devuelve la fecha de hoy a medianoche, y quitarle un día usando `INTERVAL`:

```
select current_date - interval 1 day
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NTROI48588)

Comment: Hola @Mariano. Gracias por mencionarlo. Por alguna razón, `getdate()` me funcionó en rextester, no sé por qué. Aun así, corregí eso, porque no es lo documentado. Quedo un poco curioso de porqué me funcionó.

Comment: @Mariano: Mas tarde lo averiguo, no quiero volver a caer en esa trampa.

Comment: @Mariano: Resulta que el `getdate()` era una función que otra persona había creado a mano en rextester que ejecutaba `curdate()` por debajo. Y claro, como todos compartimos los objetos que los demás crean en rextester, `getdate()` estaba disponible, y creaba la falsa ilusión de que existía esta función. Le hize un drop para beneficio de otros, pero me enseña a no confiar demasiado en lo que funciona o no en rextester.